# adding a navigator controller + view to window not rotating to landscape

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbar based application. The tabbarcontroller is on the top of the window. I tried to add a navigation controller+view on the top of the window. It works fine. but when i try to press the button which actually intiates this in landscape view it is still getting displayed in the potrait view. I set those parameters in shouldAutoRotate in the uiview of the navigator.

Should i add anything to window to make it rotate ? or what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a very simple mistake. It is like i should set the bounds and frame of the view and the that of the navigation bar's view.
1. set bounds and frame of the view which is going to be the rootcontroller of the navigation view.
2. After pushing set the bounds and frame of the same view via navigation controller.

Thats it. Things work fine. The shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method should also be tweaked to set the frame during the orientation changes.